# SSRS Migration errors rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We are trying to migrate from a 2010 Sharepoint Integrated SSRS instance to a 2014 standalone SSRS. I can connect with the accounts used to both servers. When the RSS process begins, I see the connection occur from Process Monitor, and we see data flow in to the “eval” phase of the script. When the we tell the script to execute the migration, nothing gets created on the target SSRS instance.

Script reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531017(v=sql.120).aspx

Error below:

```
Migrating Folder: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/SiteAssets ... FAILURE:
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count

Migrating Folder: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/SiteCollectionDocuments ... FAILURE:
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count

Migrating Folder: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/SiteCollectionImages ... FAILURE:
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count

Migrating Folder: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/SiteAnalyticsReports ... FAILURE:
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count
```

...

```
Migrating DataSource: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Data Connections for PerformancePoint/GreatPlains-HR-Prod.rsds ... FAILURE:
Unable to connect to the remote server

Migrating DataSource: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Data Connections for PerformancePoint/APPNAME1-Financials-Prod.rsds ... FAILURE:
Unable to connect to the remote server

Migrating DataSource: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Data Connections for PerformancePoint/APPNAME2.rsds ... FAILURE:
Unable to connect to the remote server

Migrating DataSource: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Data Connections for PerformancePoint/APPNAME3-Reporter-Prod.rsds ... FAILURE:
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

...

```
Migrating Report: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Reports/Financial/Receivables Historical Aging Trial Balance.rdl
The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.
Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found.

Migrating Report: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Reports/Financial/AnotherAPPNAME2Audit.rdl
The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.
Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found.

Migrating Report: http://SharepointSSRS/bi/Reports/Financial/APPNAME5ReportMaintenance.rdl
The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.
Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/Reports/Financial' cannot be found.
```

...

I had a problem with the command syntax at the beginning, but that seems to be resolved now. Below is the command used:

```
rs.exe -i c:\it\ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://SharepointSSRS/_vti_bin/ReportServer -v st="bi" -v ts="http://StandaloneSSRS/ReportServer" -v tu="DOMAIN\USERNAME" -v tp="PASSWORD" -t
```

Comment: `rs.exe -i c:\it\ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://SharepointSSRS/_vti_bin/ReportServer -v ts="http://StandaloneSSRS/ReportServer"  -t` This works to bring over a ton of higher level stuff (resources/folders), but it doesn't bring in the /bi/ content. I've tested from other ssrs boxes (non sharepoint) and they work great. Is there a sharepoint issue here perhaps?

Comment: After reviewing the errors, I'm thinking this is related to the folder creation issues at the beginning of the migration. Now to figure out what 
`Migrating Folder: http://flightdeck/bi/SiteAssets ... FAILURE:
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count`
means...

Comment: I'm working around it now. The SharePoint SSRS starting place is such a mess, I think it's breaking the scripts that normally work. I downloaded the rdl files, manually created the folder structure on the new SSRS, manually created the data sources, and uploaded the rdl files. I'm in process of re-linking them now. It's going to take a while, but this is the best I can do with what I have.